# Update ViewModel from View

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, view, viewmodel

Is there any event or way to know the trigger when the ViewModel is updating/updated by the View?

`INotifyPropertyChanged` and `PropertyChanged` is used when the ViewModel updated the View.

But is there any reverse?

Answer (score 1):

Changes from the view to the view model will trigger `PropertyChanged` as well, as they set properties.

Answer (score 1):

If your are binding the controls in your view to the view model, many of the pieces will update the view model as long as you make sure the binding is `Mode=TwoWay`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx

if for some reason you have set your `UpdateSourceTrigger` in the binding to be Explicit then to update the viewmodel you will need to get the binding expression and call update source

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbindingexpression.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are using binding then you can use [`Binding.SourceUpdated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.sourceupdated.aspx) and [`Binding.TargetUpdated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.targetupdated.aspx) Attached Events.